# Group and Ungroup both columns and rows in protected worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bigish spreadsheet, to protect and still be able to use the “Group” and “Ungroup” features on both columns and rows.

Below is code to do the column grouping/ungrouping with a Toggle Button. However, I have hundreds of rows of data entry and calculation that are divided into 10 sections. The number of rows in each section is likely to increase/reduce dependent upon nature of data. I tried using the Group feature on rows with below but after I used the Toggle Button, the grouping of rows disappeared.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    Columns("E:G").Select     ' this is the range of the columns
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
      , AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True

Else
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    Columns("E:G").Select     ' this is the range of the columns
    Selection.Columns.ClearOutline
    Selection.Columns.Group
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
      , AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the rows and columns in your sheet and add the following code to your workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Tabelle1.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
    Tabelle1.EnableOutlining = True
End Sub
```

This enables the user to use grou/ungroup-buttons with your protected worksheet.

Comment: Hi Jochen,Thanks for the quick response. I have followed your suggestions, but for some reason it is not working. It is probably due to something I have missed. Without the presence of a Tiggle Button, I still have the same error message stating the file is protected and cannot use the Group/Ungroup commands.

Comment: Did you change 'Tabelle1' to the Codename of the relevant sheet? You have to run the sub or save, close and reopen your workbook.

Comment: Hi Jochen, thanks a lot for that. I knew I must have missed out something. My worksheet now works well. You are a star!

Comment: Happy to help, thats what this community is for. If it solved your problem, please mark as answer and/or upvote.